# jquery plugin's chainability with each and ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, each, ready, chainability

I am trying to work on the **chainability** in a jquery plugin, and it works fine with jquery `click` [below](http://jsfiddle.net/3gjRc/),

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $('.call-parent').parent_child({
            target: '.element'
        });

        $('.call-child-1').click(function(){
            $(this).parent_child().child_1();
            return false;
        });

        $('.call-child-2').click(function(){
            $(this).parent_child().child_2();
            return false;
        });

    });

(function($) {

        $.fn.extend({ 

            parent_child: function(options) {

                var defaults = {
                    target:''
                }

                var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
                var o = options;

                var $this = this;

                var $cm = this.click(function(ei) {


                    alert('parent');
                    $this.child_1();

                    return false;

                });


                $this.child_1 = function() {

                    alert('child 1');

                };


                $this.child_2 = function() {

                    alert('child 2');

                };

                return $cm;

            }
        })
    })(jQuery);​
```

but I have the error when I use `each` or `ready` in the plugin, for instance,

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $('.call-parent').parent_child({
            target: '.element'
        });

        $('.call-child-1').click(function(){
            $(this).parent_child().child_1();
            return false;
        });

        $('.call-child-2').click(function(){
            $(this).parent_child().child_2();
            return false;
        });

    });

(function($) {

        $.fn.extend({ 

            parent_child: function(options) {

                var defaults = {
                    target:''
                }

                var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
                var o = options;

                var $this = this;

                var $cm = this.each(function(ei) {


                    alert('parent');
                    $this.child_1();

                    return false;

                });


                $this.child_1 = function() {

                    alert('child 1');

                };


                $this.child_2 = function() {

                    alert('child 2');

                };

                return $cm;

            }
        })
    })(jQuery);​
```

error message,

> $this.child_1 is not a function [Break On This Error]

Why can't I do that with `each` or `ready`? Or have I done it wrong?

Comment: function expressions don't get hoisted, so when you are setting `$cm`, `$this.child_1` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm restating my comment as an answer so you can accept:

Function expressions like `var f = function() { ... }` do not get hoisted the way named function declarations `function f() { ... }` do. So in the `each` example, setting `$cm` is calling `$this.child_1` before it has been declared. In your first example, the function is called on click, so it has already been parsed by the time it is executed.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `$` on your plugin. It conflicts with jQuery's use of it. Use something else, `a` perhaps.

Comment: the `$` is the local copy of `jQuery` in the plugin; no conflict here.